# Can an electrical subpanel be directly mounted to a hvac supply plenum?

Tags: electrical, mounting, nec

Can an electrical sub panel be directly mounted to an HVAC supply plenum. I usually see and have installed the disconnect or sub panel to the actual equipment on a wall near by or used some sort of standoff such as u-channel and spring nuts to keep the panel off the supply ductwork.

Comment: Well, you're not allowed to mount anything non-electrical *to* electrical panels, cables or raceways.  So I would expect the other way 'round to also apply.  The issue is if the tradesmen in *that* field (HVAC) has to work on *his* equipment, how's he gonna do that with yours entangled?  He's not qualified to mess with it, but his pay depends on getting to customer sign-off, so he is likely to do something moronic.

Comment: Are we talking a *disconnect* or a *subpanel* here?  Also, what type of HVAC equipment is being fed by the circuit(s)?

Comment: @Harper In most places HVAC technicians are qualified to do electrical work, as their work often depends on it.  This is especially true, if the panel we're talking about is there to supply power to the HVAC system.  If I recall, NEC simply says that the panel has to be mounted "*rigidly and securely*" on a building or other surface.  whether or not a duct can offer that, I think is going to come down to the inspector.

Comment: Some inspectors would require a plywood back plane to be mounted to the ductwork in my area but I have seen local disconnects on blowers that were mounted to the sheet metal.

Answer (score 1):

> Can an electrical sub panel be directly mounted to an HVAC supply plenum?

### Yes.

Just don't be sloppy about it.  It needs to be mounted securely.  So consider using a plywood backing, or adequate fasteners such that it is not going to fall off if someone bumps into it.

Also, ensure that no air from the plenum is vented into the sub-panel to isolate the sub-panel from condensation; and that the sub-panel will not be exposed to temperatures outside its limits.